# Using Web MIDI API on Android Chrome 52

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, web-midi

I have worked successfully with Web MIDI API and Chrome 52 on my Mac laptop - for example recognizing connected MIDI instruments. But Web MIDI API does not seem to work or recognize connected instruments when I use Chrome 52 in my Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 5.0.1. I've tried, for example, Web MIDI API tests online like [this one](https://airtightinteractive.com/demos/webmiditest/), unsuccessfully (all of which work fine on the laptop).

Native apps do recognize my MIDI devices just find in my Galaxy phone - they are connected via a working USB OTG cable. But Chrome (or Opera) are not. Any help will be appreciated. I've tried Chrome Dev and Chrome Beta, same result. I wonder if the problem is the phone, or perhaps the Android version?

UPDATE: I have also tried with an Android tablet of different brand and Android 6.0 (Marshmallow). The result is the same: `navigator.requestMIDIAccess()` is successful (it invokes the `success` callback with the `midiAccess` object as expected), but `midiAccess` has no inputs or outputs, even though a device is connected. The same tablet recognizes the device when using a native app.

UPDATE 2: Success! The problem was the electronic piano I was using to test. For some reason my laptop Chrome did find my Yamaha piano, but Android Chrome did not (they are the same version of chrome). I moved to another keyboard (a newer Roland piano) and now both Android Chrome and MacOS Chrome now detect it.

Comment: And the down vote was because...???

Comment: Do you know the USB Host specification on Android device ? I don't know if this resolve your issue but perhaps a way for...

Comment: How to find out the USB Host specification? One update: I have also tried an Android tablet (Lenovo)  - same issue. Web MIDI API seems to initialize fine, but it does not recognize any device connected via usb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the electronic piano I was using to test. For some reason my laptop Chrome did find my Yamaha piano, but Android Chrome did not (they are the same version of chrome). I used a different, newer keyboard (a newer Roland piano) and now both Android Chrome and MacOS Chrome now detect it.

Answer (score 1):

You must testing your devices for knowing is reading for USB Host. You can use application like that for testing : [app test USB Host](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.usbhostdiagnostics)

If your device don't USB Host ready you can activate that with root mode.

Comment: Thank you for your help @darkomen. The issue was the piano I was using to test. The USB Host was working fine. I changed pianos, and now Chrome is detecting it.